# Find first occurrence of non-integer in a specific column of a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, find

I have a dataframe with a bunch of integers in a column; at some point in the column, a string or letter will appear. I need to find this string or letter or non integer, then remove all data that comes after it.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What does `df.dtypes` say your column's type is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 'a', 1, 2]})

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
2  a
3  1
4  2

In [22]: df.loc[(~df.x.apply(np.isreal)).cumsum() == 0, :]
Out[22]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 'a', 1, 2]})
df.iloc[:(df.x.apply(type) == str).idxmax()]

   x
0  1
1  2
```

[image]